# Unable to declare variable within callback in Rails App

Tags: javascript, turbolinks

I'm currently working on a Rails 6 application using trubolinks. I'm working on a function to reaplace an avatar placeholder with the image selected upon upload. However, something weird is happening I'm declaring two variables, one is stated with a value the over does not.

```
document.addEventListener('readystatechange', event => {
 if (event.target.readyState === "complete") { 

/**
 * Display the image in the file input when added to the form.
 * Replace avatar with image selected.
 */
  const profileAvatarBlock = document.getElementById('profile-avatar');

  function showImage(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
      var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = function (e) {
        let avatarPreview = document.getElementById('profile-avatar-preview');
        let img =avatarPreview.children[1].setAttribute("src", e.target.result);

        debugger;
        ['width', 'height'].forEach(attribute => { 
          img.removeAttribute(attribute)
        });
        debugger;
      };

      reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
  }

  profileAvatarBlock.addEventListener('change', function() {
      showImage(this);
  })
 }
});
```

At first I thought that it was because of turbolinks so I add `"turbolinks:load",` but this didn't change anything. When I check for `avatarPreview` I get back back in the debugger but when I check `img` I get undefined. if I run `avatarPreview.children[1].setAttribute("src", e.target.result);` I also get it returned but if I assigned it to `img` is not working.

Why I cant declare a variable inside the callback? I want to understand dont care much about getting it to work.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `setAttribute` to assign `e.target.result` to the `src` attribute of the element. Then, you are assigning the return value from that function (which is always undefined) to `img`.

Try instead:

```
let img = e.target.result
```

If you really want to get the value from the children, you can try

```
let img = avatarPreview.children[1].getAttribute('src')`
```

Comment: I ended up using `let img = avatarPreview.children[1]` but the answer is still valid.

Comment: why did it returned undefined?

Comment: setAttribute is a setter. Its purpose is to set values, not to retrieve them. For that, you must use getAttribute, which acts as a getter